# What is the intuitive reason behind vanishing of $a_n$ for odd $n$ in Fourier expansion of the full wave rectifier output signal?

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The full wave rectifier signal is defined by the following---
$$f(x)=|\sin(x)|$$ and has a Fourier series expansion of the form $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1}$$
which is easy to obtain directly by formulas for the Fourier coefficients. It is seen that the $a_n$s with odd $n$ vanish identically. What is the intuitive reason for this? I mean, is there any way to guess without doing the integrations and steps involved in calculating $a_n$ that only $a_n$ with even $n$ will remain?

Comment: The period is $\pi$.

Comment: It is better to ask such questions at the DSP group. The intuitive reason is that the components of the higher frequencies has diminishing impact at the "low" frequency of the. The highest value will be for the basic frequency, which is twice the input frequency to the rectifier - which intuitively is expected. the higher frequencies are residuals that refine the shape of the original signal.